# How to open new window without titlebar in javascript

Tags: hide, titlebar

How to open new window without titlebar.

Comment: Wouldn't spammers love it if the standard ways to close their popups could be removed.

Comment: Did you mean titlebar or addressbar/menubar? They are different things.

Answer (score 3):

You can't (thankfully), at least not in common browsers in a standard web security context.

Answer (score 0):

Every window opened by Javascript will have a titlebar. You only have control over whether scrollbars, statusbars, and toolbars are present in the opened window.

To get a headless "pop-up" effect, look into a library like [LightBox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) that can do these sort of effects. You're not actually opening a new window according to the user-agent, but the behaviour is similar.